# How to Clone Repository using GitPython

Tags: repository, clone, git-clone, gitpython

I am new to Python and Git. Found GitPython library to run Git commands using Python. I am trying to clone an already created private repository on Google Cloud to my local directory on Mac. My code is as follow:

```
repo = Repo.clone_from('https://source.developers.google.com/p/my-project/r/my-project--data', 'my-local-dir', no_checkout=True)
```

And I am getting following error:

```
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128) cmdline: git clone --no-checkout -v https://source.developers.google.com/p/my-project/r/my-project-data /my-local-dir stderr: 'Cloning into '/my-local-dir'... fatal: could not read Username for 'https://source.developers.google.com': Device not configured
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to the same thing, then I discoverd [pygit2](http://www.pygit2.org), and with it I was able to clone a repository using two lines.

How? First make sure you have installed pygit2 in your python environment. I did that using the following command line:

```
pip install pygit2
```

Here the two lines I mentioned above:

```
import pygit2
pygit2.clone_repository("https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2", "pygit2")
```